# how to remove duplicate leads already present in salesforce

Tags: leads, duplicate-management

Is there a way I can get rid of the duplicate leads already present in the system based on email, then phone , name etc and retain the activity history on the leads which would be found as duplicates. We have  around 200k of leads. I know that excel is recommended but I am not having ninja skills in it. Even if I take help from someone ,would it be possible to merge the activity/campaign activity like it happens in merge lead feature. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those apps will NOT check for existing duplicates without editing the records, so they won't do the job.

If something as simple as email address is the thing that identifies your duplicates you can use this excel trick. http://crmcheatsheet.com/how-to-de-duplicate-data-for-import-to-salesforce/

An app that is really good for checking existing duplicates is Demand Tools (by the same company that make dupe blocker). It is a windows app where the data is download, scanned for duplicates, you check through the results and tell the app which records to merge. It is pretty difficult to get your head around using it, and still tedious to dedupe, but definitely worth the money (and it's free for NFPs).

Deduping is hard. It's meant to be. It's meant to shock you into the reality to never let it get that bad again, and you can use the tools mentioned above to manage them ongoing or something like Ring Lead to stop them getting in there in the first place, or wait for the native dedupe feature to be released in an upcoming release soon.

Comment: +1 for DemandTools. Once you get the hang of it, the deduplication power is amazing. Learning the tool is not for the faint of heart, though.

Answer (score 0):

The below app exchange applications may help you to remove duplicate records from your leads.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cMzEAI

You can find relevant documentation information too in app details page.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can spend a few bucks and use RingLead.  If you are looking to merge data use ringlead.  I use that and it works wonders.   As per cost, it's worth it over than spending months on cleaning your data.